# How to create json in ios from NSMutableDictionry?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to create a JSON like this

[`{"phone":"3456345"}, {"phone":"2423242"}, {"phone":"2423423"}]`

I have an array in which i have phone numbers only. Below code will create the JSON but for that i need to create dictionary first.

```
contactData =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contacts options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

I have tried to create Dictionary like this but it only enter last value because i can't have duplicate value for one key. please tell me how do i solve the problem?

```
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<[all_contacts count]; i++)
    {
        [contacts setObject:[all_contacts objectAtIndex:i]   forKey:@"phone"];

    }
```

How can i create the json here.Please tell?

Comment: I can recommend that you use "for in" in that dictionary. If you can show how final dictionary looks like?

Comment: You want to create an array of three "objects", where a JSON "object" corresponds to an iOS dictionary.  Why do you think that can be done with only one dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `all_contacts` looks like this:

```
[ "3456345", "2423242", "2423423" ]
```

Then this should work:

```
NSMutableArray *root = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *number in all_contacts) {
    [root addObject:@{ "phone": number }];
}

contactData =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:root
                                             options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                               error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=0;
NSMutableArray *contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (i=0; i<[all_contacts count]; i++) {
  [contacts addObject:@{@"phone" : [all_contacts objectAtIndex:i]}];
}

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contacts options:0 error:&error];
if (!jsonData) {
  //error here
} else {
  NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: but when i convert it into dictionary then it adds some "/" characters can you tell me why is that?

Comment: Yes here its 
{
    key = "[{\"phone\":5555648583},{\"phone\":5554787672},{\"phone\":952365285},{\"phone\":5555228243},{\"phone\":5557664823},{\"phone\":5556106679}]";
}
@Inder

Comment: Please nslog it, it will show correctly, `"` is special character so to include it in a string we have to escape it.

Comment: i have nslog it.As a string it is fine but at time converting it adds this special charecter.